# While reading package from `/var/www/mCPP/packages/cpp-students`: error: Unknown release METEOR@undefined

Tags: meteor

getting this error lately while creating custom packages in meteor
"**While reading package from `/var/www/mCPP/packages/cpp-students`: error: Unknown release METEOR@undefined**"

Comment: looks like something is wrong with your `.meteor/release` file

Comment: fixed it..the meteor apiVersion was showing undefined in the packages.js of the package. So replaced the undefined with the meteor version